# Storage file is replaced however, the firebase database link is not updated React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I am trying to sign a pdf document using React Native. After signing the document, the old file in the storage is replaced with the new updated file. However, at the same time, the firebase database image link is not updated, it is showing the old link.

Here is my try,
At the root of the project, I am passing the image link to a new nested screen,

```
navigation.navigate('Home', {
    screen: 'SignPdfDoc',
    initial: false,
    params: {
      source: `${item.postImg}`,
    },
})
```

Here, I am getting the image URL in the nested screen,

```
const sourceURI = route.route.params.source;
  const source = {
    uri: sourceURI,
    cache: true,
 };

const [fireLink, setFireLink] = useState(source.uri);
```

Now, I am trying to update the storage, and firebase database image URI, storage is updating with a change, but the firebase database is not updated, Thanks for your help.

```
const storageRef = storage().ref(`${user.email}/images/${str}`);
  const uploadTask = storageRef.put(pdfBytes);
  uploadTask.on(
    storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
    snapshot => {
      // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
      const progress =
        (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      // console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
      switch (snapshot.state) {
        case storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
          // console.log('Upload is paused');
          break;
        case storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
          // console.log('Upload is running');
          break;
      }
    },
    error => {
      console.error(error);
    },
    () => {
      // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
      uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
        setFireLink(downloadURL);
        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
      });
    },
);
```

Comment: You're don't see any call to write `downloadURL` to the database in any of the code you shared, so that would probably explain why the database isn't updated

Comment: Yes, I also agree with @FrankvanPuffelen. There is no code which relate on saving data on the database. Add that code part in onComplete callback and you updated url will be reflected in there.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to update the database, but it's not updating the database, I am getting the previous old database. Will you give hints, how can I update the database here.